# Drool or Rule Engine Performance

Tags: java, performance, drools, rule-engine

I am using rule engine(Drools) for business rules validation, but I have more than 10000 rules, So i am not sure about the performance of drool like if I use a single drl file and write all the rules in the same or I should generate rules dynamically at run-time ?

*Note traffic of data load will be high and frequent to drool. So please suggest which approach is best to use, keeping performance in the mind.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does performance matter? After you've loaded it once, do you need to load it again? Having 10k rules that you can dynamically generate implies a lot of repetition, in which case maintainability is far more important than performance.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes performance matters, we have lots of facts which will be inserted into the drools for validations. So having a file with 10k rules is better or generating drl file containing rules not 10k but close to 3k(depends on requirements) dynamically.

Comment: @AndyTurner could please let me know what are the criteria which affects the performance of drools. Like Number of rules, load of a fact, number of fact inserted to drools.